# Java (Android): Data in the string pattern

Tags: java, android, replace

I have a TextView with a string where I need to insert data.
Something like: "some text %d other text".
I don't want to have a hardcoded text in my sources.
Are there any good practices for that?

Comment: You can set it as `String text ="whatever it is"; textView.setText(text);`

Comment: I've mentioned that I don't want to have a hardcoded text in my code.

Comment: you can use any variable which holds String value, this was just an example

Comment: Use String.xml to hold all the constant values.  If it was not the right answer, then I didn't get your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Activity,

```
String param1="something",param2="important";
int param3=233;

textView.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.tmpl, param1, param2,param3));
```

In your strings.xml

```
<string name="tmpl">here is %1$s %2$s which worth %3$d</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

Store your string just as said in the res folder under `<string></string>` tag.
This will help you in translation later
Then use `String.format()` with `getString()` to form the `String` at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *append* some data to *existing data* of `TextView` then use this:

```
String finalText = (textView.getText().toString()).concat(" and new text here");
textView.setText(finalText);
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

Hardcoded text was an example:

You can simply replace it by String.

```
String someText; //This can be retrieved from webservic or by any means you want.
String finalText = (textView.getText().toString()).concat(someText);
textView.setText(finalText);
```

Comment: I've mentioned that I don't want to have a hardcoded text in my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format text with pattern like *%d %s*, you can use it  as :

```
String yourText = "default text"; // can be assigned runtime
Integer number= 2;
textView.setText(String.format("your data %s  %d", yourText, number));
```

*You can use any String variable here which holds your desired value*.

Hope it helps ツ

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.format()` method for formatting text

```
String someText="some text";
String otherText="other text";
int value=100;
textView.setText(String.format("%s  %d %s", someText,value ,otherText));
```